# ListView KeyUp Error for the Control Key

Tags: c#, listview, visual-studio-2012, keyup

ListView.KeyDown `<Ctrl>` event shows the following:

```
e   KeyData = LButton | ShiftKey | Control
    base    {KeyData = LButton | ShiftKey | Control}
        Alt false   bool
        Control true    bool
        Handled false   bool
        KeyCode LButton | ShiftKey
        KeyData LButton | ShiftKey | Control
        KeyValue    17
        Modifiers   
        Shift   false   bool
        SuppressKeyPress    false   bool
```

I don't like the fact that the `<ShiftKey>` is showing up but the Control key is showing up.
On ListView.KeyUp `<Ctrl>` event shows the following:

```
-       e   {KeyData = LButton | ShiftKey}
+       base    {KeyData = LButton | ShiftKey}
        Alt false   bool
        Control false   bool
        Handled false   bool
        KeyCode LButton | ShiftKey
        KeyData LButton | ShiftKey
        KeyValue    17
        Modifiers   None
        Shift   false   bool
        SuppressKeyPress    false
```

What gives it's weird. Look over the web to see if there are any examples of this error but could find nothing. I have tried setting the KeyPreview to true on the hosting form to no avail.

Any input is welcome.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's no error here, you simply pressed and released the Ctrl key.  The debugger just isn't very good at converting the Keys enum to a string.  It is confuzzled by that enum having the [Flags] attribute so it tries to map the individual bits in the value to a Key.

So KeyDown = (Keys.Control | Keys.ControlKey) = 0x20011.  Which the debugger mangles to
 0x20000 = Control
 
0x00010 = ShiftKey
0x00001 = LButton.

And Keyup = (Keys.ControlKey) = 0x00011.  Which the debugger mangles to
0x00010 = ShiftKey
0x00001 = LButton.

Or in other words, ignore what the debugger tells you.

Comment: I get what your saying. So how should I test the incoming KeyEventArgs to do it correctly Hans.

Comment: Test for what?  If you want to detect the Control key being pressed or released then just use `if (e.KeyChar == Keys.ControlKey)`  That's unusual.

Comment: Thanks Hans for the education. Really appreciate it.